# How to fix toolbar flickering?

Tags: android, layout, view, toolbar

I have the next layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout ... />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView ... />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Everything works fine, but when I navigate back to the fragment with this layout, there is a second when RecyclerView items are drawn on the toolbar, and everything is fine again. How can I fix it?

Flickering:
[image]

Not flickering:
[image]

Comment: In Side AppBarLayout, How you have placed Toolbar, Is it direct child or you have used CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: Also if your intention is just to use a toolbar as persistent as the top then I don't think you should use CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @Herry yes, I use CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: Does your toolbar have this app:layout_collapseMode="pin"?

Comment: Yep app:layout_collapseMode="pin"